# Create global scss variables with importing in Vue Application

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2

In my vue file after script tag I'm importing styles like this:

```
<style scoped lang="scss" src="../../styles/scss/components/_navbar.scss"></style>
```

this combined with webpack and babel works fine but I also want to have "global" variables in scss so I have main.scss file in which I'm importing other files:

```
@import 'abstracts/mixins';
@import 'abstracts/variables';

@import 'base/base';
@import 'base/typography';
```

So actually this file I'm just importing in App.vue (root of Vue SFC) but without `scoped` directive obviously:

and in `_navbar.scss` I expect to have access to variables from `main.scss -> @import 'abstracts/variables';`

but apparently I have not because it print error that variable is undefined

> Undefined variable: "$color-grey-light".

therefore currently I just import variables once again in `_navbar.scss`. How to avoid that but keep this nice (at least to me) structure with importing independent .scss files?

Comment: Have you checked the imported priorities of 'scss'? Try to load 'scss' first with '$color-grey-light' defined.

Comment: You're supposed to `@import` the global variables into each .scss file that you want them available to.

Comment: Try putting it in the `main.js` not the `App.vue`

Comment: @Dev.DY I don't know what you mean I import `main.scss` which imports `variables.scss` either in `App.vue` or in `main.js` so it always should be loaded first.
@DecadeMoon I can but I wanted to create "global" scss variables so I don't need to repeat this @import variables in every `.scss` file. 
@Michael it doesn't see variables even when I import styles in `main.js`.